# OpenCart Can I run this code to recreate my Category_Path table

Tags: opencart2.x

I had an unfortunate incident with an Import/Export Extension that ate my Category_Path table data. Now none of my categories show up in the front or backend of my site.
Will the code below work to recreate my category_path table in OpenCart 2.1.0.1?
If so how do I go about implementing it?

```
<?php
// Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
   require_once('config.php');
}
// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);


$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);

class myClass
{
   protected $db;

   public function __construct($db)
   {
      $this->db = $db;
   }
   // Database
   function repairCategories($parent_id = 0)
   {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category` WHERE `parent_id` = '" . 

(int)$parent_id . "'");
      echo "SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category` WHERE `parent_id` = '" . (int)$parent_id . 

"'<br><br>";

      foreach ($query->rows as $row)
      {
         // Delete the path below the current one
         echo "DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` WHERE `category_id` = '" . (int)$row

['category_id'] . "'<br>";
         $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` WHERE `category_id` = '" . 

(int)$row['category_id'] . "'");

         // Fix for records with no paths
         $level = 0;

         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` WHERE 

`category_id` = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' ORDER BY `level` ASC");
         echo "SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` WHERE `category_id` = '" . 

(int)$parent_id . "' ORDER BY `level` ASC<br>";
```

Comment: It will not work to recreate you `category_path`